# App insights ITelemetryInitializer doesn't add custom properties onto logs - azure function

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I am working with an azure function on .net 7, and would like to set custom properties to all logs I send to Azure Application Insights. I have followed the guide in Microsoft website with no luck.

Here is my csconfig:

```
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.21.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0"/>
```

Program.cs:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.TryAddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, CustomTelemetry >();
    })
    .Build();

  host.Run();
```

CustomTelemetry.cs:

```
public class CustomTelemetry : ITelemetryInitializer
{
public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
{
    telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.Add("GlobalProperties", "test");

}
```

All logs don't include the custom property "GlobalProperties".

Comment: Is it fine with using telemetry client?

Answer (score 0):

When you write a custom telemetry initializer you should set the properties directly on the telemetry being processed:

```cs
public class CustomTelemetry : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        if (!(telemetry is ISupportProperties supportedTelemetry))
            return;

        telemetry.Properties["GlobalProperties"] = "test";

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. With your approach it's showing on some type of logs but not all i.e. some traces, some dependencies, not at all on request. Any ideas why this may be? I'm looking at the end to end transaction and hoping to get it across all logs for the transaction

Comment: Could it be that the telemetry that does not have the custom property attached is coming from another component which does not have the telemetry initializer?

Comment: If that's the case, is there another common component(s) other than ITelemetryInitializer that you know of that I can hook into to track those? many thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on what component generates the telemetry. Of the telemetry that does not have the property attached, inspect the `cloud_rolename` property to try figure out what component has generated the telemetry.